# SQL Server / IBM DB2 interoperability

Tags: sql-server, db2, ibm-midrange, linked-server, db2-400

I'm working on a project that involves capturing data from an external service and relaying it into an IBM DB2 database. Data captured by the Web API is stored in SQL Server via Entity Framework 6 code. The table in SQL Server was structured after an existing table in DB2, using a generated script from System i Navigator to create an ISO Standard create script.

```
Remote Service --> Web API --> SQL -/-> DB2
```

The DB2 Server is set up as a linked server. I am able to select from its libraries and perform inserts manually from SQL Server Management Studio.

My goal is to run a query of the form:

```
INSERT INTO LinkedServer.SCHEMA.Table (Column1, Column2, Column3,...)
    SELECT 
        (Column1, Column2, Column3,...)
    FROM
        database.dbo.Table
```

However, when I attempt to run the above query, I am met with messages like these:

> OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "SERVER" returned message "CWBZZ5014 Value of parameter PARAMETER could not be converted to the host data type.".
>
> OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "SERVER" returned message "CWBZZ5013 Cannot convert from CCSID 13488 to CCSID 937.".
>
> OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "SERVER" returned message "CWBZZ5013 Cannot convert from CCSID 1202 to CCSID 937.".

I think there is something weird about how the insert statement is handling character encoding for all of the `char(N)` columns in the table, but I have no idea what to do about it. Have I missed something?

Comment: Probably....

CCSID 13488 & CCSID 1202 are both UTF-16...

CCSID 937 is Chinese EBCDIC

Are you dealing with Chinese characters?

Comment: Not at all, which is weird! About half of the character columns use CCSID 937, according to the table definition. It is a pre-existing table, so I can't redefine any of these.

Comment: @Charles Since I can't change the table in db2, I may be left doctoring the table I created in SQL Server until the query works. The Table designer shows an option for collation, which set to <database default>.

Comment: CCSID 37 is English...assuming english text in them, it'd be better to fix the definitions.  Otherwise this won't be the last time you have a problem.

Comment: @Charles I think the columns are using something called DBCS on these columns as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251967(v=bts.10).aspx).